# How to open git for windows shell inside a tab on ConsoleZ

Tags: windows-7, bash, shell, git, console2

I have used git bash 1.9.5 from https://git-scm.com/download/win (that URL starts a download) on ConsoleZ as shell and have no problem on open him inside a tab.

But, with the new Git for windows 2.4.5.1 RC4, it open always in a new window. What are the command line options to use as a shell and open inside a tab?

I have not found doc or info about git-bash.exe command line options.

Answer (score 11):

The following command is used in [ConEmu](http://conemu.github.io/)'s default [task](http://conemu.github.io/en/Tasks.html) for GitBash.

```
git-cmd.exe --no-cd --command=usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i
```

Actually, `git-bash.exe` is only a wrapper which starts `bash.exe`. And `git-cmd.exe` is doing the same thing. However `git-bash.exe` is an application linked for GUI subsystem, and `git-cmd.exe` is a real console application. ConsoleZ (unlike ConEmu) can't run GUI applications inside its tabs.